# @angular vs. angular2 library - which one is the latest

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I just started learning Angular2 and have a doubt with these two libraries that are present in Angular2.

Some examples has "@angular" in its import command and some example has "angular2" in its import command.

Which one among these is the latest library?

Comment: go to the official website with official documentation to see the official latest version [angular.io](https://angular.io)

Comment: Latest is `@angular`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and the latest version is @angular